# How to Send/Receive data over network in socket program in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I am working on a program which has two parts `Listner (Server)` and `Sender (Client)`. Following is my code
`Server`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("From server\n");
            string data = null;

            IPHostEntry iphostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = iphostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 32000);

            ConsoleKeyInfo key;
            int count = 0;

            Socket sock = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


            sock.Bind(localEndpoint);
            sock.Listen(5);

            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\nWaiting for clients..{0}", count);
                Socket confd = sock.Accept();

                int b = confd.Receive(buffer);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, b);

                Console.WriteLine("" + data);
                data = null;

                confd.Send(msg);

                Console.WriteLine("\n<< Continue 'y' , Exit 'e'>>");
                key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.KeyChar == 'e')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nExiting..Handled {0} clients", count);
                    confd.Close();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    break;
                }
                confd.Close();
                count++;
            }
        }
```

`Client`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[10];

            IPHostEntry iphostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAdress = iphostInfo.AddressList[0];            
            IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 32000);            

            Socket client = new Socket(ipAdress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);            

            try
            {
                client.Connect(ipEndpoint);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket created to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                byte[] sendmsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello My Name Is Shaiwal Tripathi\n");

                int n = client.Send(sendmsg);

                int m = client.Receive(data);

                Console.WriteLine("" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Transmission end.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

It's working fine on single computer. But when I am trying to run it on LAN network by assigning the `IP Address` manually, I'm getting the following error.
`The requested address is not valid in its context`
This is how I'm assigning the `IP Address`.

```
            IPAddress ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse("168.168.0.8");
            IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 32000);            
            Socket client = new Socket(ipAdress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            client.Bind(ipEndpoint);
            client.Connect(ipEndpoint);
```

My goal is to send data to a target computer on network and target computer should receive the incoming data.

Comment: The endpoint given for `client.Bind` is the *local* endpoint, not the *remote*  endpoint.

Comment: @KlausGütter Can you please elaborate and give me the solution ?

Comment: Just omit that line.

Comment: @Fildor did the same as you suggested, not succeeded